# Server Error on connection using Socket IO

Tags: android, kotlin, sockets, socket.io, wss

I am using the **Socket.io** for my connection to the server with **wss** protocol , below is my code i am facing issues as server error. Same URL with the **WebSocket** i am not facing any issue socket gets connected, kindly let me know what i am missing from my below code

```
package com.example.socketapplication
import android.util.Log
import io.socket.client.IO
import io.socket.client.Socket
import java.lang.Exception
import java.net.URISyntaxException


class SocketManager {
    private var socket: Socket? = null
    private var url = "wss://xyz.com/primus/?_primuscb=dBAJyfE&EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=sp1BWFXgxS2hBz7YAFQt&t=WZKvQcZ&b64=1"
    init {
        try {
            socket = IO.socket(url)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    fun connect() {
        socket?.connect()
        socket?.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR) {

            Log.i("SocketConnection", "Not connected ${it.first().toString()}")
            // Now you can safely use socket.connected()
        }
    }

    fun disconnect() {
        socket?.disconnect()
    }

    fun isConnected(): Boolean {
        return socket?.connected() ?: false
    }

    fun onMessageReceived(listener: (String) -> Unit) {
        socket?.on("message") { args ->
            val message = args[0] as String
            listener.invoke(message)
        }
    }

    fun sendMessage(message: String) {
        socket?.emit("message", message)
    }
}
```

Dependency Used:

```
implementation ("io.socket:socket.io-client:2.1.0")
```

Calling Part

```
private val socketManager = SocketManager()
    socketManager.connect()
```

Comment: "i am facing issues as server error" is not a problem description.

Comment: i have made a clear explanation in the description, Kindly look into it for providing the solution if you know on it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The library you're trying to use doesn't support that protocol.  From the docs at https://socket.io/docs/v4/

> What Socket.IO is not caution
>
> Socket.IO is NOT a WebSocket implementation.
>
> Although Socket.IO indeed uses WebSocket for transport when possible,
> it adds additional metadata to each packet. That is why a WebSocket
> client will not be able to successfully connect to a Socket.IO server,
> and a Socket.IO client will not be able to connect to a plain
> WebSocket server either.
>
> // WARNING: the client will NOT be able to connect! const socket =
> io("ws://echo.websocket.org");

Also from the same page:

> caution
>
> Socket.IO is not meant to be used in a background service for mobile
> applications.
>
> The Socket.IO library keeps an open TCP connection to the server,
> which may result in a high battery drain for your users. Please use a
> dedicated messaging platform like FCM for this use case.

While there are ways you can use it, for the most part you should avoid websockets in mobile programming.  Particularly if you expect the app to ever be backgrounded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so there is no way of using the socket.io with wss, you are saying right ?

Comment: Correct.  It's a different protocol, and the library is not compatible with plain WS servers.  Although the warnings about using websockets for a mobile app at all are applicable to any type of web socket including wss-  it's ok for use if you only need it while your app is in the foreground, if you need it while in the background it's not really going to work on Android due to unreliability of background processing for power saving reasons.